# Excel "Go To Special" Crashes on Large File

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to find all cells that have constants. I'm use excel 2010 and the file has 206963 rows and 9 columns. They are all filled with constant values. When I search for constants excel crashes.

Questions:

1. Anyone know of a workaround?
2. Is there a list of the limitations of these functions and when they should not be used?

The following at the steps:

1. In home-> Find & Select --> Go to Special...
2. Select Constants.
3. Click OK.

Excel just hangs and eventually selects all the rows but crashes. I tried this with the other "go to special" functions and the same thing happened with large amounts of data.

Comment: Have you tested this on at least two other PCs to confirm that its an Excel limitation and not an unlucky combination of other things?

Comment: No. I have not. I restarted my computer a few times. I'll test on other pcs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use of any simple database. Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition instance. And the search for and manipulate data will be instantaneous. If you have the necessary elements to create an index. Use the right tools.